# Wi-Fi adapter in a Dell Inspiron keeps disconnecting

Tags: virus, wireless-adapter, physical-environment

I’m using a Dell Inspiron and the Wi-Fi adapter keeps on disconnecting, it allows me to connect using ethernet. I know that it isn’t disabling since it isn’t turned off, it doesn’t even give me the option to enable it. I believe that it may either:

1. Be a virus. I have reset to factory settings but did not wipe the computer and re-install the OS (Windows 7) and it still persists.
2. It is physically lose in my computer and when I shift it disconnects and reconnects, since if I try walking away and leaving it alone for a while I can turn it on and it will be back to normal.

I’m not sure if those are even the problems. If anyone has any recommendations I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you asked something similar so the answer is the same. Update your drivers http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Products/laptop?app=drivers